# hiphop compilation fails on 90%

Tags: linux, php5, centos6, php

I've been working with hiphop on fresh centos-6.3 with gcc-4.6.2 and followed the following guide for hiphop compilation https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/Building-and-installing-HHVM-on-CentOS-6.3 . However compilation fails on 90% and produces errors, few of them are given below, can someone assist me on it?

```
[  1%] Built target timelib
[  2%] Built target xhp
[ 10%] Built target mbfl
[ 11%] Built target afdt
[ 14%] Built target folly
[ 15%] Built target double-conversion
[ 15%] Built target sqlite3
[ 15%] Built target lz4
[ 67%] Built target hphp_runtime_static
[ 77%] Built target hphp_analysis
[ 90%] Built target ext_hhvm_static
Linking CXX executable hhvm
scalar_arrays_0.no.cpp:(.text+0x562): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
../../bin/libhphp_runtime.a(literal_strings_0.no.cpp.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
literal_strings_0.no.cpp:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
literal_strings_0.no.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
literal_strings_0.no.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [hphp/hhvm/hhvm] Error 1
make[1]: *** [hphp/hhvm/CMakeFiles/hhvm.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

From your own link "If you met some issues on build, You could also try to upgrade your Boost to 1.50 version and GCC to 4.6.1 version: You could follow this instruction for build BOOST: https://github.com/jackywei/HOW-TO-BUILD-HHVM-WiKi/wiki/Build-&-install-Boost-1.50-in-CentOS-(CentOS5.2-&-6.3-are-both-verified)"

I'm guessing you're using an older version of boost and thats the issue - since all the issues are boost related.

Comment: I've not compiled boost before. You might want to paste the complete output of that compilation in your question since "failed updating 56 targets" looks off, and the formatting makes it very hard to read. Don't forget to use the code tags

Comment: boost compilation produced the following error , 
./boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory